# Win 7 RD "Install certificate" button missing even in admin mode

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, trusted-root-certificates

I'm connecting from home to my office box (both win 7) using **RemoteDesktop** through **gateway**. Connection gets through but I get the gateway **certificate not trusted** message immediatelly. As per various sources and similar scenarios I click the "view certificate" in hope to find the "**install certificate**" button. However the button is simply not there even when I run the mstsc.exe with "**run as admin**" option.

My account **is in administrators** group and I have already **disabled the UAC**. Still no option to install the certificate.

Any insights would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although I still do not see the "install certificate" even when on fresh installation of Win 8, these steps did it:

- click on "view certificate" > "details" tab
- save the certificate to file with "copy to file.." button
- double-click on just saved certificate file
- import it into proper store (trusted root CA in my case)

Comment: You may just need to make sure it was imported to the machine store instead of the user store.

Answer (score -1):

For the missing "Install Certificate" button, try the following: 
Close all browser windows (IE and Edge)
Locate the Internet Explorer in your START menu
Right click on it and select "Run As Administrator"
Once it's opened, now enter your https URL
Continue to web site option > View Certification > Install Certificate should now be visible.